# Fastest Way to Parse Html in Perl

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I have following HTML string:

```
<html>
<head>
 <!-- Head Content Goes Here!! -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Body Content Goes Here!! -->
</body>
</html>
```

Suggest me the fastest way to extract everything that lies inside `<body></body>` tag?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,cpan is always powerful and perl especially good at text parsing.
This is what you need: http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Parser

Answer (score 1):

1. install mojolicious
2. then run mojo command on the command line

mojo get 'http://google.com' 'html > body' text